# Почему не работает подсветка zf2 lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-2

Здравствуйте!
Поиск с помощью Lucene:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\Utf8\CaseInsensitive());
$index = Lucene\Lucene::open($searchIndexLocation);      
$searchResults = $index->find($validatedQuery['searchQuery']);
```

Затем должны подсвечиваться слова по которым производился поиск:

```
\ZendSearch\Lucene\Search\QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('UTF-8');
$doc = Html::loadHTML($high, false, $defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8');
$doc->highlight($validatedQuery['searchQuery'], $colour = '#66ffff');     
$highlightedHTML=$doc->getHTMLBody();
```

С английским текстом все нормально работает, а вот с русские слова либо не подсвечиваются вовсе, либо подсвечиваются отдельные буквы в других несовпадающих с запросом словах. Причем если запрос начинается с заглавной русской буквы, то вообще поиск не работает. В чем может быть дело? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте следующую код в конструкторе класса, где используете Lucene

```
Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Analyzer::setDefault(new CaseInsensitive());
Lucene\Search\Query\Wildcard::setMinPrefixLength(0);
Lucene\Search\QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('UTF-8');
Lucene\Search\QueryParser::setDefaultOperator(Lucene\Search\QueryParser::B_OR);
```

Используйте свой аналайзер CaseInsensitive():

```
class CaseInsensitive extends Utf8Rus
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addFilter(new Lucene\Analysis\TokenFilter\LowerCaseUtf8());
    }
}


class Utf8Rus extends Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\Utf8Num
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function tokenize($data, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
    {
        return parent::tokenize($data, $encoding);
    }
}
```

И все будет работать.